# Not able to mount directory after updating fstab

Tags: unix, redhat, mount, fstab

On a Windows file share I created a folder and shared it with a service account.

I have added a mount point entry to `fstab` like this:

```
//server/folder /mnt/folder cifs credentials=/root/creds/creds,noperm
```

Where the creds file contains credentials for above mentioned service account.

Then run `mount -a` to activate the mount point.

It gives an error like:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
Couldn't chdir to /mnt/folder: No such file or directory
```

I have tried mounting the directory manually and receive the same error.

What the heck am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah.  I had not created `folder` in `/mnt/folder` on the UNIX side.  Did `mkdir /mnt/folder`.

I was then able to see `folder` in `/mnt` but it was empty.

Did a `mount -a` and can now see the contents of the Windows share in `/mnt/folder`

I seems like I had to do `mount -a` from `/etc` as when I issued the command from `/mnt` it just hung for a while until I killed it and then tried from `/etc`